# Android SQlite, How do you pass two values to another activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, android-intent, spinner

I am modifying my program to get its values from a database and I am having some issues and I am a little bit confused on what to do. I've been stuck for days, I would appreciate the help.

When I select an item on my spinner(populated from database), I need it to pass the INT value along with it so I can send it to another activity.

So far my code looks like this, the database utility:

public class DbUtility {

```
static final String DB_NAME="food";
static final String BEEF_TABLE="beef";
static final String CHICKEN_TABLE="chicken";

SQLiteDatabase db=null; 
Context context;

public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {           
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BEEF_TABLE (_id INT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR, cookTime INT);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO BEEF_TABLE values(1,'Skirt Steak', 23000);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO BEEF_TABLE values(2,'Flank Steak',23000);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO BEEF_TABLE values(3,'Filet Mignon',23000);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CHICKEN_TABLE (_id INT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR, cookTime INT);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO CHICKEN_TABLE values(1,'Breast',20000);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO CHICKEN_TABLE values(2,'Wings',10000);");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO CHICKEN_TABLE values(3,'Burger',30000);");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
    }   
}
public DbUtility(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
}
public SimpleCursorAdapter getBeefAdapter()
{
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(this.context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor beefCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM BEEF_TABLE", null);
    while(!beefCursor.isLast())
    beefCursor.moveToNext(); //I don't understand why but it's necessary (alternative call c.getCount() )
    String[] beefType=new String[1];
    int[] to=new int[1];
    beefType[0]="name";
    to[0]=android.R.id.text1;
    SimpleCursorAdapter beefAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, beefCursor, beefType, to);
    beefAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    db.close();
    return beefAdapter; 

}   


public SimpleCursorAdapter getChickenAdapter()
{
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(this.context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor chickenCursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM CHICKEN_TABLE", null);
    while(!chickenCursor.isLast())
    chickenCursor.moveToNext(); //I don't understand why but it's necessary (alternative call c.getCount() )
    String[] chickenType=new String[1];
    int[] type=new int[1];
    chickenType[0]="name";
    type[0]=android.R.id.text1;
    SimpleCursorAdapter chickenAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, chickenCursor, chickenType, type);
    chickenAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    db.close();
    return chickenAdapter;  
}   

public int getCookTime(String theTable, String theFood) 
{
    DatabaseHelper dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(this.context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    int TheCookTime = 0;
    Cursor foodCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + theTable + " WHERE name='" + theFood + "'", null);
    TheCookTime = foodCursor.getInt(foodCursor.getColumnIndex("cookTime"));
    return TheCookTime;
}
```

I need to grab, cookTime INT and pass it to my spinner activity:

```
package com.tsilo.grillbuddy;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class ChickenActivity extends Activity {

```
int option1value;
int option2value;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinner);

    final DbUtility db=new DbUtility(this);


    SimpleCursorAdapter beefAdapter=db.getBeefAdapter();
    final Spinner beefSpinner=(Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    beefSpinner.setAdapter(beefAdapter);

    SimpleCursorAdapter chickenAdapter=db.getChickenAdapter();
    final Spinner chickenSpinner=(Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    chickenSpinner.setAdapter(chickenAdapter);

    Button TimerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.TimerActivityButton);
    TimerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String beefSelection = (String) beefSpinner.getSelectedItem();
            option1value = db.getCookTime(DbUtility.BEEF_TABLE, beefSelection);
            String chickenSelection = (String) chickenSpinner.getSelectedItem();
            option2value = db.getCookTime(DbUtility.CHICKEN_TABLE, chickenSelection);
            Intent timer = new Intent (ChickenActivity.this,TimerActivity.class);
            timer.putExtra("option1", option1value);
            timer.putExtra("option2", option2value);
            startActivity(timer);
        }
    });

}
```

**Edit**: As you can see I incorporated the solution, I was required to change my spinners to final for them to work and change DbUtility to db. It compiles fine with no errors, and I am able to get to my chicken activity when I click it, but I now get a force close when I click my Timer Button, my DDMS looks as follows

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT...** OK, try this for your TimerButton onClick() method. Your SimpleCursorAdapters will need to be declared as 'final' but your Spinners no longer need to be neither does your DBUtility db instance in the ChickenActivity.

```
    TimerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            option1value = getCookTime(beefAdapter);
            option2value = getCookTime(chickenAdapter);

            Intent timer = new Intent (ChickenActivity.this, TimerActivity.class);
            timer.putExtra("option1", option1value);
            timer.putExtra("option2", option2value);
            startActivity(timer);
        }
    });
```

Also, instead of having the getCookTime() method in the DBUtility class, add this to the ChickenActivity class instead. I've added some android.util.Log calls so you can test it's working the way you need it.

```
    public int getCookTime(SimpleCursorAdapter adapter) {
        String theName = "None";
        int theCookTime = 0;

        Cursor theCursor = adapter.getCursor();
        theName = theCursor.getString(theCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        theCookTime = theCursor.getInt(theCursor.getColumnIndex("cookTime"));
        android.util.Log.i("ChickenActivity", "theName: " + theName);
        android.util.Log.i("ChickenActivity", "theCookTime: " + theCookTime);
        return theCookTime;
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to figure this out. I have int option1value declared in my class, that is what I was going to use to pass it to a putExtra. I put the code in my chicken activity under beefSpinner.setAdapter. I am not sure where to place the query, can you elaborate a little bit more on that. This is my first android app and my first database incorporated in a program so I am very weak on this.

Comment: I made my String query look like this:        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DbUtility.BEEF_TABLE + " WHERE name='" + selectedItem + "'";

Does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Then you need to get at least a readable instance of the database and execute that query. This will return a 'cursor' (you might want to use a SQLiteCursor) and you can use getColumnIndex("cookTime") and use that to getInt(int columnIndex) to get the cookTime value.

Comment: I still need a little help, I added something to my post, maybe an idea on how to get it. I am not sure on how to do what you are describing. Would you mind showing an example?

Comment: See my edit - it's not perfect and just gives the idea of what I'm trying to put across.

Comment: @SickNick: See my latest edit. I'm not actually sure what you want option2value for but I've illustrated getting the name of the selected beef cut from the spinner and (by default) passing DBUtility.BEEF_TABLE to the getCookTime() method. If you access the chickenSpinner then obviously you'd pass DBUtility.CHICKEN_TABLE instead.

Comment: Ok looks like we have a new problem, It force closes when I click the Timer Button, I posted an image of the DDMS, just right click and save it so you can view it in a readable size, I figured its a lot easier to read in a picture rather than pasting the output in text and losing its format. By the way thank you so much for helping me I really appreciate it.

Comment: @SickNick: No problems WRT the help, hopefully we'll get it solved. I threw you off in the wrong direction however but I think my re-edit of my answer will hold the key. My fault, you already had the adapters which would do the work and I was thinking in a different way.

Comment: Yes! :-) it works!!! I can not thank you enough MisterSquonk! Thank you thank you thank you! P.S. That answer acceptance just got me the privilege to vote up ;-)

Comment: That's great news! Glad to be of help and to have had the opportunity to learn a couple of things myself along the way. Thanks for the vote up and the answer acceptance.